# SQLite - Every row in a column of reals contain only an R

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database, in which a column in a table (which is of type REAL), contains an R in every row. I have never seen this before, and it kind of ruins the method that reads the database, as it expects a real value.

Has anyone seen these R values before?

The picture below should make it clear if my description is not enough. Greatful for help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How did you insert the values? As far as I know, SQLite does not check datatypes and you can store anything you want in any column, whatever the datatype declared.

Comment: I haven't made the database, so I really don't know. So you think there just has been some mistake made during creation of the database?

Comment: Not in creation, during insertion of the data.

Comment: Well, still, It's a machine that generates these tables during a measurement, and I wasn't there, and don't know who operated it. This is the only database of this kind where I have encounter this column of R's.

Comment: I can't see very well the image but the Rs seem to appear well in column DPKEY. Each cell contains a bunch of numbers separated with a colon or a semi-colon. Even without the R, those values together are never of type real. Since sqlite has the peculiarity of "ignoring" the field type and assigning a type per value, all you have are strings.

Comment: I now know what they are. I emailed a developer I found (and who answered this late a friday evening), and he says it stands for Remote.

But on topic: I guess I'm stuck with reading the values as strings, and convert to double in my C# code. I just thought that it would be slower.